# How to add custom type properties to the AppProps type from "next/app"?

Tags: typescript, next.js

From the official docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#custom-app

We get this:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

I need to add my custom properties to the `pageProps` property.

But the `AppProps` type does not seem to allow that:

[image]

It does not allow any generic customization to the `AppInitialProps` type.

And here is the `AppInitialProps` type from `next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.d.ts`:

[image]

What is the best practice to add my own type for the `pageProps` property?

Comment: Couldn't you declare you own `AppInitialProps` type then extend `AppProps` to include it?

Comment: @juliomalves yes, that's kind of what I've ended up doing. Feel free to write an answer if you have a cleaner approach than the one I took. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've come up with:

```
export type CustomPageProps = {
  preloadedState: Types.Redux.PartialRootState
}

export interface CustomAppProps<P = CustomPageProps> extends AppProps<P> {
  pageProps: CustomPageProps
}

const App: React.FC<CustomAppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  console.log("Rendering App");

  const store = useStore(pageProps.preloadedState);
  useSetListeners(store);

  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I had to break it into two types `CustomPageProps` and `CustomAppProps` because I had to access in the App's render body as `pageProps.preloadedState`. And I also had to type and extend the `AppProps<P>` in order to comply with the `<Component {...pageProps}/>` call.

If any one has a better suggestion, I would like to know.

If I wasn't using it in the App's render body I could do something like that and it would work fine.

```
export type CustomPageProps = {
  preloadedState: Types.Redux.PartialRootState
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps<CustomPageProps>> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps}/>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
});
```